# Setting the Canvas clock to system time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, time, clock

I have done a clock in canvas, which ticks every second. I want to set the time to the System clock. I have got the time using the function "var date = new Date();". But could not figure out how to get the angles according to the time.

Help much appreciated.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RaoBurugula/6aLauwaj/2/

```
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctxline = c.getContext("2d");
        //variables
        var seconds = 0,minutes = 0 , hours = 0;
        var iSeconds = 0, counterSeconds = 0, xSeconds=180,ySeconds=0;
        var increaseSeconds = 6 * Math.PI /180;
        var iMinutes = 0, counterMinutes = 0, xMinutes=180,yMinutes=0;
        var increaseMinutes = 6 * Math.PI /180;
        var iHours = 0, counterHours = 0, xHours=180,yHours=0;
        var increaseHours = 6 * Math.PI /180;
        //ctxline.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        //drawLinesInCircle();
        clockDesign();
        getAndSetCurrentTime();
        clock();
        function clockDesign(){
            var iClockHours = 0, counterClockHours = 0, xClockHours=180,yClockHours=0;
            var increaseClockHours = 30 * Math.PI /180;
            var hours = ["12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
            var gradient=ctxline.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
            jQuery.each( hours, function( i, val ) {                 
                xClockHours = 180 + Math.sin(counterClockHours)* 140;
                yClockHours =  180 - Math.cos(counterClockHours)* 140;
                counterClockHours += increaseClockHours; 
                //alert(counterClockHours);
                // Create gradient
                ctxline.font="30px Verdana";
                ctxline.textAlign = 'center';
                gradient.addColorStop("0.5","red");


                ctxline.fillStyle=gradient;
                ctxline.fillText(val,xClockHours,yClockHours);

            });
        }

        function getAndSetCurrentTime(){
            var dt = new Date();
            var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
            //alert(time);
        }

        function clock(){
            //Seconds
            seconds += 1;
            xSeconds = 180 + Math.sin(counterSeconds)* 120;
            ySeconds =  180 - Math.cos(counterSeconds)* 120;    
            counterSeconds += increaseSeconds;
            iSeconds += 6;

            //minutes
            xMinutes = 180 + Math.sin(counterMinutes)* 110;
            yMinutes =  180 - Math.cos(counterMinutes)* 110;
            //hours
            xHours = 180 + Math.sin(counterHours)* 100;
            yHours =  180 - Math.cos(counterHours)* 100;

            if(seconds == 60){  
                //alert("one min");
                minutes +=1;
                seconds =0;
                counterMinutes += increaseMinutes; 
                iMinutes += 6;
            }

            if(minutes == 60){
                hours +=1;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;
                counterHours += increaseHours; 
                iHours += 6;
            }

            if(hours == 12){
                hours = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0; 
            }

            draw(xSeconds,ySeconds, xMinutes, yMinutes, xHours, yHours);
            setTimeout(clock, 1000); 
        }

        function draw(xSecondsTo,ySecondsTo, xMinutesTo, yMinutesTo, xHoursTo, yHoursTo){
            ctxline.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
            clockDesign();
            ctxline.beginPath();
            //seconds line
            ctxline.strokeStyle = ("#EDDE54");
            ctxline.lineWidth = 1;
            ctxline.moveTo(180,180);     
            ctxline.lineTo(xSecondsTo,ySecondsTo);
            ctxline.stroke();
            ctxline.closePath();

            //miuntes line  
            ctxline.beginPath();
            ctxline.strokeStyle = ("#545EED");
            ctxline.lineWidth = 4;
            ctxline.moveTo(180,180);     
            ctxline.lineTo(xMinutesTo,yMinutesTo);
            ctxline.stroke();
            ctxline.closePath();
            //Hours line 
            ctxline.beginPath();
            ctxline.strokeStyle = ("#BE1616");
            ctxline.lineWidth = 7;
            ctxline.moveTo(180,180);     
            ctxline.lineTo(xHoursTo,yHoursTo);
            ctxline.stroke();
            ctxline.closePath();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/6aLauwaj/9/

Just like Luckyn suggested but need to adjust the hour.

```
var secs = dt.getSeconds();
seconds=secs;
counterSeconds = secs * (increaseSeconds);

var mins = dt.getMinutes();
minutes = mins;
counterMinutes = mins * increaseMinutes;
//alert(time);
var Hours = dt.getHours() % 12;
Hours *= 5;
hours = Hours;
counterHours = (Hours * increaseHours) + (30 * counterMinutes / 360); //Need to consider the minutes, take minutes angle and calculate how much further hour should be angled.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i followed Luckyn and it worked well.

Comment: @Rao The difference is the hour arm. It's 12:25 here now and if you check this fiddle you'll see the hour arm is halfway between 12 and 1, where it should be. On the other fiddle the hour arm is right on 12. Hour arm's angle needs to take the minutes into consideration.

Comment: @artm agreed with your + for the hours angle :), he can also do it the same for minutes, you can just use previous/12 rather than 30*previous/360 ^^

Answer (score 1):

You already have all the code you need : each second you're doing `counterSeconds += increaseSeconds;`

Just init your counters with current date using the same process :

```
function getAndSetCurrentTime(){
  var dt = new Date();
  var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
  //alert(time);
  counterSeconds = dt.getSeconds() * increaseSeconds;
  counterMinutes = dt.getMinutes() * increaseMinutes;
  counterHours = dt.getHours() * increaseHours;
}
```

**edit fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/6aLauwaj/16/

Comment: Hi Luckyn, Thanks for that. worked well. here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/RaoBurugula/6aLauwaj/14/
i did not see any delay, I might be wrong too.

Comment: my bad, you are using counters to do your angle, wich is increment after the x/y calcul :)

Comment: also from your last fiddle you can just call clock once to start increment rather than `setTimeout(getAndSetCurrentTime, 1000);`) or you're gonna request the date every second (better let the init on getAndSetCurrentTime, then let cloack do a simple incrementation)

Comment: also as suggest artm, you can init sconds, minutes and hours. They have no effect at all on the clock, but they can be easy getter if you need current time from the clock

Comment: is it a bad idea call to call date every second?

Comment: I think it'll consum more ressource to constantly call date rather than just doing a +1 and 3 if. I might be wrong, anyways here's a fiddle with suggestions :)  http://jsfiddle.net/6aLauwaj/16/   (there is still iSeconds, iMinutes and iHours that I don't understand :( )